# NSURLConnection making Asynch call a Synch and handle self signed certificate

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsrunloop

I am trying to make a Asynchronous Call , a Synchronous one. I know its not a better idea to do it. But, I do need such to code to handle Auth Challenge of Self Signed Certificate while Keeping the call still as Synchronous.

But, I am not sure whether it is a perfect way to make Asycnh call a Synch one.

```
-(NSData*) startConnection{
     NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

   while(!isFinished && [[NSRunLoop currentLoop] runMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]){
   }


   return responseAppData;
}


     - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
      //Code to handle Certificate
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
       [responseAppData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
         isFinished=YES;
}
```

I also thought of using the while Loop as below, so which one should be used?

```
   while(!isFinished ){
   }
```

Comment: a better way is to use block coding

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's the opposite. If you want to handle these NSURLConnectionDelegate methods, you need to use **asynchronous** calls, NOT synchronous. Otherwise the delegates are never called.

Comment: My code works Asynchronous, responds to delegate and because of while condition it works as Synchronous code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 typedef void (^onDownload)(NSData *data);

@property (nonatomic,assign) onDownload block;


-(void) startConnectionwithBlock:(onDownload) pBlock;{
    self.block = [pBlock copy];
}
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    block(self.data);
}
```

Comment: I do have method to work with block, but I need a synchronous method to handle self signed certifcate

Comment: i think you can manage at didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge method for this?